# Passing data from router to server file node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to build a web app using node.js and I would like to pass data from my router, file which processes a form, to my server file that will actually emit events to the other user connected.

**router.js**

```
module.exports=function(app) {
    const express = require('express');
    const User = require("./public/classes/User");
    const router = express.Router();
    const {check, validationResult} = require('express-validator');
    const {matchedData} = require('express-validator/filter');

    var userlist = new Array();


    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('index', {
            data: {},
            errors: {}
        })
    });

    router.post('/enter', [
        check('username')
            .isLength({min: 1})
            .withMessage('Username is required').trim()   //implement personalized check
    ], (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.render('index', {
                data: req.body,
                errors: errors.mapped()
            })
        }
        const data = matchedData(req)

    });
    return router;


    //MOVE TO SUPPORT
    function find(name) {
        return 1;
    }

}
```

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const layout = require('express-layout');
const app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
const routes = require('./router')(app);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require("fs");



app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const middleware = [
    layout(),
    express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')),
    bodyParser.urlencoded(),

];

app.use(middleware);

app.use('/', routes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry can't find that!");
});

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});



io.on('connect', onConnect);

function onConnect(socket) {
    var contents = fs.readFileSync("./public/rooms.json");
    let rooms = JSON.parse(contents);
    socket.emit('parse',rooms);
    socket.on('join',function (name, room) {
        console.log(name+" "+ room);
        socket.join(room);
        socket.user=name;
        socket.room=room;
    })
}



server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`App running at http://localhost:3000`);
});
```

I would like to pass the processed data of my post request to the server, how do I do that?

Comment: The reason you want to send it to the server file is so that you can emit it via socket to the client(s) right?

Comment: Yes that's exactly the reason why i want to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is send the data processed in the route handler to the client(s), you don't need to send it to the `server` file first, you can emit from the route handler. To do that, you would have to store a reference to the socket object so you can use it in other places apart from the socket connection call-back function.

Update your `onConnect` function in `server.js` to store a reference to socket in app locals:

```
function onConnect(socket) {
  // Store the socket object in app locals
  app.locals.socket = socket;
  var contents = fs.readFileSync("./public/rooms.json");
  let rooms = JSON.parse(contents);
  socket.emit('parse',rooms);
  socket.on('join',function (name, room) {
      console.log(name+" "+ room);
      socket.join(room);
      socket.user=name;
      socket.room=room;
  })
}
```

And in the route handler, you can emit the data whenever you want:

```
router.post('/enter', [
  check('username')
    .isLength({ min: 1 })
    .withMessage('Username is required').trim()   //implement personalized check
], (req, res) => {
  const errors = validationResult(req);
  if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.render('index', {
      data: req.body,
      errors: errors.mapped()
    })
  }
  const data = matchedData(req)
  // Emit your data here:
  app.locals.socket.emit("data", data);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

May be you have forgot to export routes from route.js .
Use `module.export = route;` 
in route.js file.

Comment: You're right part of my code it's missing on the question i will edit that. But that's not actually my probleb. If that was the answer I would have got an error of some kind . My concern is how to make the data processed by the form available in my server.js file.

Comment: I would like to access this ```const data = matchedData(req)``` in ```server.js```